# Part of my SSD is in Windows 7 is reserved and I can’t seem to access it

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, ssd

I recently added a 120 GB SSD to my PC and mirrored the system on my 500GB HDD. When that happened it ended up reserving 40GB of the SSD to the system. But the system is on the other 80GB. So now I can only use 2/3 of the SSD.

Also my 500GB HDD has “lost” 100MB, which would be nice to have also.

I’m running Windows 7 x64 bit.

Here is an image of my Disk Management:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/DnpUUMQ.png]

Comment: That picture would help a bunch.. :) Publish the picture on Imgur.com or someplace similar, then provide the public link to it here and someone with more rep can edit it in for you.

Comment: http://imgur.com/DnpUUMQ

Comment: can you add more information about how you "mirrored the system on your 500GB" drive? I presume you mean that you imaged the 500GB drive and used that image to set up the SSD. The 100MB "system reserved" partition is normal for windows. A 40GB one is not.

Comment: I used a USB Boot-up program to image the system from the HDD to the SSD.

Comment: You don't want to get rid of that reserved partition it exists for a reason.

Comment: 100MB of the 500GB HDD doesn't matter, if that a normal thing.
But the 40 GB would be nice to have or being able to lower it and release more of it. Either way is fine.

Comment: the SYSTEM partition (boot manager, bitlocker config) is too large. You need a 3rd party tool to resize it. The inbox Windows tool doesn't support this

Answer (score 0):

*and mirrored the system on my 500GB HDD*

What does that mean. Did you clone the OS or did you use an image to transfer the OS and what program did you use.

***it*** ended up reserving 40GB of the SSD to the system

What is "it" - and did you check what's in that partition.

*Also my 500GB HDD has "lost" 100MB, which would be nice to have also.*

Was there a shadowstorage in the HDD. Check with this command:

**vssadmin list shadowstorage**

for the rest, run [**WinDirStat**](https://windirstat.info/). That will tell you what's on the disk.